# Redux&React handle data the right way

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Assume the following situation: As a logged-in user, you're accessing your own profile page. The header menu will show your avatar as a logged-in user, and the rest of the page will show your user public information.

You got a list of users from the api, and you need to handle data from 2 of these users: the logged-in user and the user which profile page is being accessed (in the situation above, it's actually the same user).
Duplicating the data in `store.users`, `store.currentUser` and `store.myUser` would be a very bad idea (need to sync these 3 occurrences of the data everytime it gets modified). But I do not want my components using the current or logged in user data to be re-rendered everytime some lambda user data gets modified in the list of users.

How would you proceed in order to avoid data duplication, speed up data handling time (avoid costly list operations like filter/find), and avoid unnecessary re-rendering ?

After some thinking, I'm thinking of implementing it this way,
Data are stored as follow:

```js
store = {
  users: {
    1: {
      name: 'John',
    },
  },
  currentUser: 1,  // user which profile page is being accessed
  myUser: 1,       // logged in user
};
```

Now, the UserDetails component can be connected as follow:

```js
@connect(state => {user: state[state.currentUser]})
export default class UserDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>User profile: {this.props.user.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

and the page header using the logged in user data can be connected as follow:

```js
@connect(state => {user: state[state.myUser]})
export default class HeaderMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Logged-in user: {this.props.user.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

But I'm not convinced that this is an ideal solution. Will have to test whether the re-rendering is truly avoided or not.
Your thoughts are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I would store the details of the logged in user in the Redux store. Whatever data necessary to manage the user's session and render the persistent header. For other user profiles I'd load the data on-the-fly from the backend.

For example, if you had a route `/profile/:id` and this was the URL `foo.com/profile/99`

```
class Profile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: null,
            loading: true
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        api.get('/getUser', {userId: this.props.match.params.id}, response => {
            this.setState({
                user: response.user,
                loading: false
            });
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The data from other users is used in many other places, so requerying the API countless times is very inefficient.
I lazy-load all the users public data from my root component, so all the data are available from the store, no need to re-query the API for data already available in the store.

Comment: @Fandekasp Did you downvote me based on your opinion of what is more efficient? Your approach isn't scalable. Loading all the data on the front end will bog down the browser. The data will be out-of-sync if someone else updates from a different source. You're writing more code that's likely unneeded which makes your code base more work to maintain. If certain components re-use user data you can pass the data from one component to the other. The Redux store should be used when it makes sense to use it. It's not a blanket solution for managing all your app's data.

Comment: Reverted the vote since I indeed voted based on a personal opinion and not facts. I'm trying to apply the 3 principles of redux, the first one being "single source of truth" (ie the store). I'm also trying to keep the data only where it's being needed instead of forwarding props down countless components (but I realize I've been influenced by  GraphQL fragments in this matter). 
Anyways, I still believe your answer to be wrong in that API data should be treated as immutable data (like props), while the component state variables are mutable datas (loading is a good example of state)